# Marionettejs - How to unsubscribe from Vent function subscribed?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

How can I unsubcribe from Vent function that subcribed already with 'On' method

```
Vent = new Backbone.Wreqr.EventAggregator();
Vent.on("change:caption", function(){
  console.log("caption changed");
});
Vent.trigger("change:caption");
```

Is there is anyway to remove / stop listening to "change:caption" from ***Vent._event*** stack?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Vent.off("change:caption"); //unsubscribe
```